# Subdividing toward a unit distance graph in the plane

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I just want to ask, what is the **significance of subdividing a graph toward a unit distance graph**? I have seen several studies of it but I cannot find what its importance.
I mean, like the study of Gervacio and Maehara.

> Subdividing a Graph Toward a Unit-distance Graph in the Plane.
>
> Severino V. Gervacio, Hiroshi Maehara Eur. J. Comb 01/2000;
>   21:223-229. DOI:10.1006/eujc.1999.0348 Source: DBLP ABSTRACT The
>   subdivision number of a graph G is defined to be the minimum number of
>   extra vertices inserted into the edges of G to make it isomorphic to a
>   unit-distance graph in the plane. Lett (n) denote the maximum number
>   of edges of a C4-free graph on n vertices. It is proved that the
>   subdivision number of Knlies betweenn (n− 1)/2 −t(n) and (n− 2)(n−
>   3)/2 + 2, and that of K(m, n) equals (m− 1)(n−m) forn≥m(m− 1).

Answer (score 3):

"Its importance" is a subjective judgement. As the introduction of the paper explains, not
every graph is isomorphic to a unit-distance graph, but every graph is homeomorphic to a unit-distance graph by inserting vertices into edges. So it is a natural question to ask how many insertions are necessary.

Unit-distance graphs are of great interest in the area of [geometric graph theory](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=conmseries&item=CONM-342).
They have been studied at least since 1946 when Erdős posed the question of counting
unit-distance pairs of points, a still not entirely solved problem. More recently, unit-distance graphs have been used to model ad hoc wireless networks.

     [image]

     <sub>See the earlier MO question, "[Erdős, Harary, Tutte's “dimension of graph”: Progress in last 48 yrs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140768/)"</sub>